# Is etoro a best place to start buying stocks for a beginner?

Tags: investing, long-term

Since I had a monthly income (2 years ago) I was hesitating to start or not investing (buying EFTs, reits) ,for a long term, some of my monthly earnings, I was googling "The best websites to buy stocks" and most of websites suggest etoro.

My questions:

1. how etoro claiming they have 0 fees? is it really true?
2. is etoro a best starting platform for a beginner like me?
3. is it possible with etoro to automate the deposit of, ex:$100 monthly from my bank account or credit card?
4. I live in europe, will I have a problem with tax authority when withdrawing money? does etoro apply a fee when withdrawing?
5. with etoro can I buy some reits (ex: VNQI)

Thank you.

Comment: Googeling a phrase returns the company with a claim closest to your search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you certain that the broker you are considering is offering real shares of stock traded directly on stock exchanges? Many companies offering stocks for trade are actually just offering CFDs (contracts for difference). In these cases, you don't get beneficial ownership of shares and your trades don't go to the exchange. Instead, you pay the broker for a contract with a payout based on how much and in what direction the real price of the stock on the exchange moved. In general, CFD brokers aren't as closely regulated as real stock brokerages that provide you with ownership of real shares.

Profits and losses on CFDs vs trading real shares of stock can be taxed differently. This will vary depending on what country you are in.

Personally, I feel safer buying stocks from the exchange using a stock brokerage that's licensed and regulated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I understand now more, can you please provide some links how to find a broker please? and one last questions, when buying stocks does it imply you automatically get dividends from the company you own their stocks?

Comment: @marOne - I'm not in Europe, so can't give a good recommendation. What I would do is visit several of the largest exchanges. Some (not all) stock exchanges are kind enough to list all properly licensed firms that trade on them. CFD brokers may or may not pay dividends. Real brokerages will pay all dividends that a shareholder is entitled to. Make sure to buy the stock before what's called the ex-date or you won't get the dididend that dividend. Dividends are generally added to your account balance. I hope Europe doesn't have dividend collection fees. I've seen those in some HongKong brokers.